# Fetch specific date modified using filemtime() function

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch and display on my page specific files with the same date modified using filemtime(). But I can only display the set of dates not the specific date that I input in the form that I did. Can someone please enlighten me :( I'm kinda newb in php

```
<?php
$date1 = strtotime($datemod);
$files = glob($directory . '*.txt');
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $file) {
if($file->isDot()) continue;
    echo '<center>'.date('Y-m-d',filemtime($file->getPathName())) .     '</center>';
    $datemodified = date('Y-m-d',filemtime($file->getPathName()));
    if($date1 == $datemodified){
        echo '<center>'.date('Y-m-d',filemtime($file->getPathName())) . '</center>';

    }

}

if ( $files !== false)
{   $filecount = count( $files );
    echo "<br><center>There are <h1>".$filecount."</h1> txt files in the     folder!</center></br>";}
    else
    {echo 0;}
?>
```

Comment: please show us the code that you used previously and its result

Comment: result: 2016-04-15
2016-04-12
2016-04-12
2016-04-12
2016-04-12
2016-04-12
2016-04-20
2016-04-22

There are
8

txt files in the folder!

Comment: Click "edit" which is under your question, and paste your code there. It's very hard to read inside the comments.